# How do I select disctinct but Include all other variables in the final table?

Tags: sql, select, sas, distinct

I have a table with 200+ columns.  I want to select distinct on only one variable, but have all of the 200+ columns in the final dataset.

Is there a capture all variables statement that can be placed after the select distinct?

```
  proc sql;
        create table test as
        select distinct X (keep = _All_)
        from source
;quit;
```

Comment: You want to keep only one observation per value of X? Do you care which one you keep?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use SQL for this.  Use PROC SORT.

```
proc sort data=source out=test nodupkey;
  by X;
run;
```